# How to iterate over inputs of certain class with Prototype

Tags: prototype, arrays, invoke

I want to iterate over an array of inputs that belong to certain class (eg."required"). How can I traverse it and get their values ? Something like

```
$$('input required').invoke(function(e){
      alert(?input value?)
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close:

```
$$('input.required').each(function(i){
    console.log($F(i));
});
```

All inputs with the class of `required` will be iterated through and their value displayed to the Firefox console. If you don't use Firefox just change `console.log` to `alert` to see the results.

Comment: John, thanks for your reply, I'm almost there, 2 more things if you'd be so kind; in the code:

    $$('input.required').each(function(i){
          console.log(i.name+':'+$F(i));
          if ( i.empty() ) {
            alert("Must Enter "+i.name);
            i.focus();
            return;
          }
        });



1) is empty() good enough to check for null and whitespace-only strings?
2) return doesn't break the loop, how can I leave the "each" loop ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure empty() will work for null. Try `throw $break` to break out of the each() loop.

Answer (score 0):

It works me.

example code:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;

    $$('.product-name').each(function(i){

        var eleHeight = i.getHeight();

        if (eleHeight > maxHeight){
            maxHeight = eleHeight;
        }
    });

    $$('.product-name').each(function(i){
        i.setStyle({
            height: maxHeight+'px'
        });
    });
});
```